# The Jacobson radical and quasi-regular elements in polynomial rings -- trouble understanding a proof.

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

The concept of the Jacobson radical is quite new to me and I have to give a talk about a certain paper concerning it. I agreed to do this to find motivation to finally study this concept properly, as the paper was advertised to be accessible. Part of it is, but I ran into trouble when the author actually started using facts about the Jacobson radical. The paper is *On the Jacobson Radical of Polynomial Rings* by J. Krempa (1974).

Rings aren't necessarily unital here. An element $r$ of a ring $R$ is said to be *quasi-regular* when there is an element $s\in R$ such that $$r+s-rs=0.$$ (At least this seems to be the definition the author is using. Jacobson calls such elements *right* quasi-regular.) $R_n$ will denote the ring of $n\times n$-matrices over $R.$ A ring is *nil* iff all of its elements are nilpotent. A ring is *radical* iff it's equal to its Jacobson radical.

The aim of the paper is to prove the following statement.

> Let $R$ be any ring. Then $R[x]$ is radical iff for all $n$ the ring $R_n$ is nil.

The proof starts with the following lemma.

> For any ring $R$ and any $n\geq 1,$ there exists a monomorphism $f_n:R[[x]]\longrightarrow R_n[[x]]$ such that
>
> (i) unimportant (ensuring that when $R$ is an algebra, the monomorphism respects the additional structure);
>
> (ii) $f_n(R[x])=f_n(R[[x]])\cap R_n[x];$
>
> (iii) If $p\in R[x]$ and $\deg p\leq k n,$ then $\deg f_n(p)\leq k.$

The proof of this lemma relies on two quite simple tricks. First, we send an element $p\in R[[x]]$ to an infinite matrix over $R$ like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140080/is-this-action-of-mathbb-fx-on-bigoplus-i-0-infty-mathbb-f-natura). Then we "cut" the matrix into $n\times n$ blocks, obtaining an infinite matrix over $R_n.$ Then we notice that the resulting matrix is the image of a power series $r\in R_n[[x]],$ and we put $$f_n(p)=r.$$

The restriction of $f_n$ to $R[x]$ is a monomorphism to $R_n[x].$

Now, there's a second lemma, the one I'm having trouble with.

> Let $R$ be any ring. Then if $R_n$ is a nil ring, any polynomial of degree $\leq n$ is quasi-regular in $R[x].$

The author takes any $p\in R[x]$ of degree $\leq n.$ He notes that $\deg f_n(p)\leq 1.$ And he says that $f_n(p)$ is quasi-regular in $R_n[x],$ which he doesn't explain and I don't understand. We have $f_n(p)=ax+b,$ where $a,b\in R_n[x]$ are nilpotent. I know that nilpotent elements are always quasi-regular, but in a noncommutative ring, the sum of two nilpotents doesn't have to be nilpotent. $(1)$ Why is $f_n(p)$ quasi-regular in $R_n[x]?$

The author denotes by $q$ the element of $R_n[x]$ such that $f_n(p)+q-f_n(p)q=0.$ Then the paper says this.

> Since $R[[x]]$ is radical, there exists $p'\in R[[x]]$ such that $p+p'+pp'=0.$

$(2)$ Why is $R[[x]]$ radical? $(3)$ And why does it imply that $p$ is quasi-regular? From [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical) Wikipedia page, I know that the Jacobson radical is the set of all elements $a$ of $R$ such that for any $r\in R,$ $ar$ is quasi-regular. So a radical ring is a ring in which any product of two elements is quasi-regular. But what about the elements which aren't products? There can be such elements in non-unital rings...

After that the author notes that $$f_n(p)+f_n(p')-f_n(p)f_n(p')=0,$$ and this is what follows:

> The ring $R_n[[x]]$ also being radical, the element $f_n(p)$ has exactly one quasi-inverse. Therefore $q=f_n(p')\in f_n(R[x]),$ i.e. $p'\in R[x],$ since $f_n$ is a monomorphism of $R[x].$

I'm completely confused at this moment. I'm not even sure what the author means by "quasi-inverse". He seems to have changed the definition of "quasi-regular" to a one-sided version. $(4)$ Does it apply also to "quasi-inverse"?

Then it is said that from this lemma the non-obvious implication of the theorem follows.

**EDIT** Thanks to rschwieb's reference, I've been able to find answers to questions $(3)$ and $(4)$.

Comment: It looks like it will take some thinking. I have a feeling that the problem of showing the product/sum of noncommuting nilpotent elements is circumvented by the matrix ring being nil, because its entries will record long sums/products of noncommuting elements. Is the author using induction in lemma 2?

Comment: @rschwieb I don't think he does. At least he doesn't explicitly say he does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proof of the theorem in the paper, using lemmas proved in [my other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146077/23211).

> **Theorem.** Let $R$ be any ring. Then $R[x]$ is a radical ring iff for all $n$ we have that $R_n$ is nil.

*Proof.* To prove $\Longrightarrow,$ we use [this fact](http://www.mathreference.com/ring-jr,matrix.html). Let $R[x]$ be radical. By the linked theorem, for every $n$ we have that $(R[x])_n$ is radical, and therefore $R_n[x]$ is radical by Fact 5. It follows from Fact 4 that $R_n$ is nil for every $n$.

Conversely, suppose that $R_n$ is nil for all $n$. Let $p\in R[x], \;\deg p\leq n$. Then $\deg f_n(p)\leq 1.$ By Fact 3, $f_n(p)$ is quasi-regular in $R_n[x],$ that is we have a $q\in R_n[x]$ such that $$f_n(p)+q-f_n(p)q=0.$$

By Fact 2, $R[[x]]$ is radical. Therefore, there exists $p'\in R[[x]]$ such that $$p+p'-pp'=0.$$ Then also $$f_n(p)+f_n(p')-f_n(p)f_n(p')=0.$$ But $R_n[[x]]$ is also radical by Fact 2. Therefore, $q=f_n(p'),$ whence $p'\in R[x].$ Therefore $R[x]$ is radical.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an explanation about the paper, but it is meant to help with the notion of *quasiregularity* here.

If you denote $r\circ s:=r+s-rs$, then you can show that $\circ$ is a binary operation on $R$ which is associative and has unity element $0$. (I read about this in Heatherly and Tucci's paper *The circle semigroup of a ring*, but I think Jacobson is usually credited for the idea.) If the ring has identity, then $1$ actually acts as an absorbing element! That is $a\circ 1=1\circ a=1$ for all $a\in R$. This is quite the reverse casting of 0 and 1 compared to the original operation!

Of course we can consider right and left ("quasi"-)inverses in this operation $\circ$. If you check, the definition you wrote for quasiregular was: $r\circ s=0$, that is, $s$ was a right inverse for $r$ (remember that 0 is the identity). As with any associative binary operation, if $r$ has any left inverse, then it has to be equal to $s$, but it is also possible that it has no left inverses.

Lam puts some exercises about this in *First course in Noncommutative rings* (and so you would also be able to see it in his *Exercises in classical ring theory* also)

- when $R$ has $1$, the circle semigroup is monoid isomorphic to the semigroup of the ring
- if a right ideal consists entirely of right quasiregular elements, then the elements are also left-quasiregular.
- $\{a\in R\mid aR \text{ is right quasiregular}\}=rad(R)$

Comment: How are rings without identity and their radical important? It's a silly question to ask, because I am already convinced of their utility when there is a unit, but it seems to me we can easily go from a ring without identity to one with one, by adjoining a unit, just add $\mathbb{Z}$, which also explains the circle product and which brings the radical theory back to that of rings. I am really confused.

Comment: Jacobson meticulously explored many ring/module theoretic problems in great generality, especially without the convenience of an identity. Several natural structures (Lie algebras, Baer and Rickart rings from functional analysis) are interesting without identity. Adjoining a unit does not trivialize the theory of rings without unity. Also see [this:](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16168/applications-of-rings-without-identity). I *prefer* rings with unity but I'm weary of the "adjoin 1 and forget" mantra.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat The theory of ring radicals is simply simpler without he requirement that rings contain a unity. It's convenient to consider ideals to be subrings. If I remember correctly, in one proof of Wedderburn's theorem, the difficult part is to prove that there is a unity in a certain ring, which makes the rest of the proof quite simple. This is what my mentor told me, and other ring theorists in my department have expressed a similar opinion. Another example is that it would be impossible to say "nil ring" if all rings had identity elements.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm going through the exercises along with Jacobson's book and it appears that two of my questions are going to be answered.

Comment: I have added two answers. I would be very grateful if you'd take a look at them. I seem to be missing something...

Answer (score 2):

This post contains the necessary lemmas. The proof of the main theorem is in [my other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146094/23211).

I still don't require rings to have identity elements. I will first *define* a radical ring.

> **Definition.** A ring $R$ is *radical* iff every element of $R$ is quasi-regular, that is has a quasi-inverse. [Equivalently](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/136810/23211), $R$ is radical iff every element of $R$ has a left (right) quasi-inverse.
>
> **Notation.** Every ring is an algebra over $\mathbb Z,$ and as such can be embedded in a standard way in a unital algebra over $\mathbb Z.$ I will denote this algebra by $R^*.$
>
> **Fact 1.** An element $p\in R[[x]]$ for some unital ring $R$ is invertible iff its constant coefficient is invertible in $R.$

*Proof.* We use the embedding given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140080/is-this-action-of-mathbb-fx-on-bigoplus-i-0-infty-mathbb-f-natura). An upper-triangular infinite matrix over $R$ with all entries on the diagonal equal to $a\in R$ is invertible in the ring of all infinite matrices iff $a$ is invertible in $R.$ It is a matter of a simple calculation to prove that if $A\in M_\triangledown(R)$ (as defined on the linked page) is invertible in $M_\infty(R),$ then it is also invertible in $A\in M_\triangledown(R).$

> **Fact 2.** Let $R_n$ be a nil ring for some $n$. Then $R[[x]]$ is a radical ring.

*Proof.* If for some $n$ we have that $R_n$ is nil, then $R$ is nil, because $R$ can be embedded in $R_n.$  Let

$$x=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots\in R[[x]].$$

Since $a_0$ is nilpotent, we have that $1-a_0$ is invertible in $R^*.$ Then $$1-x=1-(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots)=(1-a_0)-a_1x-a_2x^2-\ldots$$

has a constant coefficient that is invertible in $R^*.$ Therefore, by Fact 1, $1-x$ is invertible in $R^*[[x]],$ and so $x$ is quasi-regular.

> **Fact 3.** If $R$ is a nil ring, and $f\in R[x]$ such that $\deg f\leq 1,$ then $f$ is quasi-regular.

*Proof.* Let $f=a+bx\in R[x].$ Since $a$ is nilpotent, $1-a$ is a unit in $R^*.$ Since $R$ is an ideal in $R^*$, we have that $$(1-a)^{-1}b\in R,$$ and so $(1-a)^{-1}b$ is nilpotent. Therefore $$1-f=(1-a)-bx=(1-a)(1 - (1-a)^{-1} b x)$$ is a product of two units in $R^*,$ and therefore a unit. (Thanks to Matt E for pointing out a mistake in this part of the proof.) We note that this would not work for a higher degree of $f$.

> **Fact 4.** If $R[x]$ is a radical ring, then $R$ is nil.

*Proof.* Let $r\in R.$ Since $R[x]$ is radical, there is $f\in R^*[x]$ such that $$(1-rx)f(x)=1.$$ But also $$(1-rx)(1+rx+r^2x^2+\ldots)=1.$$ But then we must have $$R^*[x]\ni f=1+rx+r^2x^2+\ldots.$$ Hence $r^n=0$ for some $n$, and $r$ is nilpotent.

> **Fact 5.** For any ring $R,$ we have $R_n[x]\cong (R[x])_n.$

*Proof.* $(R[x])_n$ is an algebra over the center of $R[x]$ with entry-wise scalar multiplication. Of course, $x$ is an element of that center. Let

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
(r_0^{11}+r_1^{11}x+\ldots+r_{k_{11}}^{11}x^{k_{11}}) & \ldots & (r_0^{1n}+r_1^{1n}x+\ldots+r_{k_{1n}}^{1n}x^{k_{1n}}) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 (r_0^{n1}+r_1^{n1}x+\ldots+r_{k_{n1}}^{n1}x^{k_{n1}}) & \ldots & (r_0^{nn}+r_1^{nn}x+\ldots+r_{k_{nn}}^{nn}x^{k_{nn}})
\end{pmatrix}
\in (R[x])_n,
$$

where all $k_{ij}$ are the indices of the maximal non-zero coefficients in the polynomials (if the polynomials are nonzero). We can take $k=\max_{i,j}k_{ij}.$ Then we can write $k$ instead of $k_{ij}$ everywhere above, taking the redundant $r_{ij}$ to be zero. Then the above is equal to

$$\sum_{i=1}^k
\begin{pmatrix}
r_i^{11}x^i & \ldots & r_i^{1n}x^i \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
r_i^{n1}x^i & \ldots & r_i^{nn}x^i
\end{pmatrix}
=
\sum_{i=1}^k
\begin{pmatrix}
r_i^{11} & \ldots & r_i^{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
r_i^{n1} & \ldots & r_i^{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
x^i,
$$

which is nothing less than a polynomial in $R_n[x].$ I don't know how to argue that this ends the proof but I dare say it is obvious that it does. It's clear that considering the last sum to be in $R_n[x]$ is licit.

These are all of the lemmas needed to understand the proof in the paper I believe. I will post the proof shortly, but in another answer because this one is already barely possible to type in.

Comment: Dear ymar, In the proof of Fact 2, I don't think it's the nilpotence of $b$ that you use, but rather the nilpotence of $(1-a)^{-1} b$.  (This element *is* nilpotent, since it belongs to the nil ring $R$.)  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Thank you for the comment. I see why $(1-a)^{-1}b$ being nilpotent works. But why doesn't my argument do?

Comment: Dear ymar, Perhaps I'm just being stupid, but since $R$ is not necessarily commutative, $b$ being nilpotent doesn't imply that $(1-a)^{-1}b$ is nilpotent (without the nil hypothesis on the entire ring).  Now $(1-a) + b x = (1-a)(1 + (1-a)^{-1} b x),$, and so to show that $(1-a) + b x$ is invertible, you need to show that $1 + (1-a)^{-1}b x$ is invertible, which needs nilpotence of $(1-a)^{-1} b$.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE I've corrected the proof. Is is fine now? I hope it is because it's very difficult to edit it because of all the latex!

Comment: @MattE It's me who was being stupid... For some reason I believed that the sum of a unit and a nilpotent is always a unit in any ring, which is clearly not true because for example
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Thank you very much for pointing this out.